# SQL Server decimal calculation error

Tags: sql-server, decimal

I understand that this is not the typical question here, sorry about that.

So recently I met a strange thing in Microsoft SQL Server. It seems to round decimal(30, 10) calculations to the sixth digit after the decimal point. It is very simple to show it:

```
select 0.0000009 * 1;
-- 0.0000009, perfect
select cast(0.0000009 as real) * cast(1 as real);
-- 9E-07, that's also 0.0000009, sehr gut!
select cast(0.0000009 as decimal(18,10)) * cast(1 as decimal(18,10));
-- same number – no surprise
-- but:
select cast(0.0000009 as decimal(30,10)) * cast(1 as decimal(30,10));
-- yields 0.000001!
```

But let me go forward:

```
select cast(0.0000008 as decimal(30,10)) * cast(1 as decimal(30,10));
-- 0.000001, same thing
﻿select cast(0.0000007 as decimal(30,10)) * cast(1 as decimal(30,10));
-- 0.000001, same thing    
select cast(0.0000005 as decimal(30,10)) * cast(1 as decimal(30,10));
-- 0.000001, same thing
--     
select cast(0.0000004999 as decimal(30,10)) * cast(1 as decimal(30,10));
-- 0.000000! why the hell is it rounding!?
-- and the crown jewel:
select cast(0.00000049999 as decimal(30,10)) * cast(1 as decimal(30,10));﻿﻿
-- 0.000001, rounded up to get the same thing as above, insane!
```

At first I thought this was a simple calculation or decimal vs binary representation error, so I started with digging down to the actual record and see the hexadecimal memory dump there ([full story here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/theres-just-one-more-thing-laszlo-tenki)). But of course it didn't help and I realized the reason when I tried the second code block above to come to the conclusion that there's a rounding somewhere in the process.

Just out of curiosity - because I reported to Microsoft already - what would you do, how to go forward investigating this error? I'd like to find out what operations are going on in the background.

Comment: If you read [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/03/29/multiplication-and-division-with-numerics/), seems like internally there's a truncation to numeric(38,6)? Because some precision is lost, multiplying to `cast(1.0 as decimal(13,3)` will give `0.0000005`. While multiplying it to `cast(1.0 as decimal(14,3)` will give `0.000000`.  I'd call that a bug.  It's safer to cast them to float instead.

Comment: Also, [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/233f7380-3f19-4836-b224-9f665b852406/about-multiplication-in-sql?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Definitely a bug, not a question.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why are you using SQL Server for calculation instead of using a general-purpose language like Python or Ruby?

Comment: @warsong There are numerous instances where calculation makes sense in the DB, for example in functions or stored procedures, calculated columns or even when returning data to a reporting layer.  Why add the complexity of another language and technology layer just to do some simple calculations on your data?

Comment: @warsong this is a set of ETL processes I'm creating, loading huge amounts of data. They are far more complicated than I'd like to start them in SSIS or Talend or anything similar, need a bunch of tables which define the control parameters, the chain of forex categories you need to switch from and to over the year at specific dates or to define the calculations, some of which must be done during the loading. So it made sense to start a database for this and thus I kept everything, even the logic in SQL. The whole thing is pure SQL procedures, though it has a user interface (.NET)